# Is this multiple join on 2 tables possible?

Tags: sql, join, reference, limit

I have 2 tables and I am having trouble joining it to give me the desired output.

First table is called Future. It is future meetings I have.

```
Date         Name    Subject          Importance    Location
7/08/2020    David   Work             1             London
7/08/2020    George  Updates          2             New York
7/08/2020    Frank   New Appointments 5             London
7/08/2020    Steph   Policy           1             Paris
```

The second table is called Previous. It is previous meetings I have had.

```
Date         Name    Subject         Importance    Location     Time      Rating
1/08/2020    David   Work            3             London       23.50     4
2/10/2018    David   Emails          3             New York     18.20     3
1/08/2019    George  New Appointments5             London       55.10     2
3/04/2020    Steph   Dismissal       1             Paris        33.20     5
```

Now what I need to is to reference my previous table by name to see the previous meetings I have had with this person and I want all the data from the Previous Table there. I also need to limit it to only showing maximum 5 previous meetings with each person.

```
Date         Name    Subject         Importance    Location     Time      Rating
7/08/2020    David   Work            1             London       -         -
1/08/2020    David   Work            3             London       23.50     4
2/10/2018    David   Emails          3             New York     18.20     3
7/08/2020    George  Updates         2             New York     -         -
1/08/2019    George  New Appointments5             London       55.10     2
```

The Name column will need to be a left join, but then i need to just do a regular join on the other columns. Also unsure how to limit the name results to a maximum of 5 of the same value. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I suggest combining the two tables into a single table, which would make your life much easier.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @TimBiegeleisen. That way may take a bit of work but may be easier in the long run. Easy enough to get future meetings with a where clause on the date, but then how would I reference the table to get the previous 4 meetings with each client?

Comment: Depending on your SQL version, you would the `LAG` function for that.  The functionality you would need with a single table would probably already be built into your SQL version.

Comment: Agreed with Tim, you could have another column to identify meetings that already happened, or you can carry this knowledge with you knowing that a null time and rating means it didn't happen yet. It's easy to deduce that for someone that never saw the table. But it's still quite tricky to return a limited group.. you would have to create some with groups.

Comment: @undecided000 . . . And what happened to Steph and Frank?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want `union all`:

```
select m.*
from ((select Date, Name, Subject, Importance, Location, NULL as time, NULL as rating
       from future
      ) union all
      (select Date, Name, Subject, Importance, Location, time, rating
       from previous
      ) 
     ) m
group by name, date desc;
```

You can apply other conditions to this result.  It is not clear what other conditions you really want, but this is a start.

Comment: Thanks for your time. So this returns everything in my table? I only want to see the ones I have a meeting with tomorrow or in the future, and I also need to limit the results to only showing a maximum of 4 previous meetings. Is it possible to add this to this syntax? Also to answer your other question, I forgot to add Frank and Steph to the bottom table, they should be there.

Comment: change "select Date, Name, Subject, Importance, Location, time, rating from previous" to "select top (4) Date, Name, Subject, Importance, Location, time, rating from previous" to get only top 4 results for previous entries

Comment: Thank you Vytautas. I am using postgressql. I used Limit function instead after previous but still inside the bracket, this has limited me to only getting 4 results from previous. I want to get up to 4 for every different name.